# How to run my computer's time setter as a silent backgound PID?

Tags: python, process, background, pid

I guess my computer's battery of bios got dead; consequently the system time is never accurate, it is sometimes stuck at 1 PM with a faulty date, so I came up with this code with the idea of fetching universal time from an api and setting my computer's time accordingly.

My problem is how to make my code run in the background without printing any ping results to the screen or showing anything. I need it to function as a PID and keep alive as long as the computer is on.

PS: I am using Windows 7

```py
from json import loads
from urllib.request import urlopen
import logging
from win32api import SetSystemTime
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import re
from os import system
while True:
    # connection is dead with 1, connection is alive with 0
    connection_is_dead = 1
    while connection_is_dead != 0:
        connection_is_dead = system('ping -n 1 google.com')

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.disable(level=logging.INFO) # logging off
    logging.info('Connection is up...')
    try:
        with urlopen("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/africa/tunis") as time_url:
            text = time_url.read()
            logging.info('Time api imported...')
        mytime_dict = loads(text)
        time_now = mytime_dict['datetime']
        logging.info(time_now)

        time_stamp = re.compile(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d+)[+|-].*')
        time_match = list(map(int, re.match(time_stamp, time_now).groups()))

        # winapi32.SetSystemTime(year, month , dayOfWeek , day , hour , minute , second , millseconds )
        dayOfWeek = datetime(*time_match[:3]).weekday()
        SetSystemTime( *time_match[:2],dayOfWeek, *time_match[2:6], 0)
        logging.info('Time updated successfully...')
        #system('exit')
        sleep(1800) # 3O min / reset time every 30 min
    except:
        logging.error('Time was not updated due to an unexpected error... ')
        #system('exit')
```

Comment: Are you currently running it using Windows scheduler? What screen rendering do you get at the moment?